# Implicit (bool) and == operator override - handle if statements correctly

Tags: c#, operators, overriding, implicit

I have a custom class with implement both the `==` and the `implicit` for boolean operator.

Is this the correct way to handle all possible, if ==/!= statements and get the expected result?
Like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(bool @bool, Foo foo)
    {
        return Equals(foo, @bool);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(bool @bool, Foo foo)
    {
        return NotEquals(foo, @bool);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Foo foo, bool @bool)
    {
        return Equals(foo, @bool);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo foo, bool @bool)
    {
        return NotEquals(foo, @bool);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        return Equals(foo, fooB);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        return NotEquals(foo, fooB);
    }
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo foo)
    {
        try { return foo.Result; }
        catch { return false; }
    }

    private static bool Equals(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo, null))
        {
            if (object.Equals(fooB, null))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        if (object.Equals(fooB, null))
            return false;

        return foo.Result == fooB.Result;
    }
    private static bool NotEquals(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo, null))
        {
            if (object.Equals(fooB, null))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        if (object.Equals(fooB, null))
            return true;

        return fooB.Result != foo.Result;
    }
    private static bool Equals(Foo foo, bool @bool)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo, null))
            return true;

        return @bool == foo.Result;
    }
    private static bool NotEquals(Foo foo, bool @bool)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo, null))
            return false;

        return @bool != foo.Result;
    }

}
```

I am especially wondering about the fact that its seems you really need to implement overloads for either

```
if (new Foo() != true)
```

and

```
if (true != new Foo())
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of having a method `bool PossibleResult()`?

Comment: @Jon I am developing a EntityFramework App, with Firebird as my DataBase sadly the current version of Firebird doesnt support boolean nativly so I want to create a custom class assign this to the fields in my EDMX file. With the implicit conversion to bool and the overriding of equality operators I can then use DataBinding as if it would be a boolean and dont need to write wrappers for every bool property.

Comment: I 'm not at all sure that I have the whole picture, but it sounds like build time code generation could help you. Google T4 templates, they are built into VS and fit the bill exactly.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - or whether this would actually be better on CodeReview. I really don't like your implicit conversion to bool implementation though... catching *all* exceptions and swallowing them, instead of just checking for null? Ick.

Comment: And are you *sure* that the null handling is what you want? `Foo f = null; if (f == true)`...?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, it would have been better on code review.. sry about that. The only Q I had with this code, if I need to write overloads for (bool b, Foo f) and with Foo at the fist position (Foo f, bool b), seemed kinda strange to me that this seems to be a requirement. About your question with `Foo f = null; if (f == true)`, yes thats exactly like I desire it. This class is used for return values, it replaces the TryXXX(out YYY) pattern, since one of my co-workers is against this pattern and wanted 1 return value. So we have `Foo<T>` with a property Result of `T`, which would be the out.

Comment: @RandRandom: I'm fine with getting rid of the `TryXXX` pattern, but that doesn't mean you need to have implicit conversions. Have a look at how we do it in Noda Time, for example: http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Text_ParseResult_1.htm

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thought about this as well, thats the reason why the property `Result` in the code is public in the first place, but I was confronted with the Q. "So instead of having to write out xxx everytime, I have to type .Result every freakin' time?" And I was like with a smile on the face "Sure why not? You dont really ask for a implicit conversion to bool or are you?" and than he "Now we are talking buisness.", so I was kinda forced to do this. Since I have never done a implicit conversion to bool I was wondering if everything is correct. Isnt a topic you find on the internet easily.

Comment: Well, there's "correct" as in "doing what you intend" and then there's "pleasant code I'd like to work with." I personally try to avoid code which tries to be too "clever" like this whenever possible. This feels like a type which is far too surprising to be to my taste.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but I'm curious: Why must your bools be called `bool` w/ `@` syntax? Couldn't you have just named them anything else?

Comment: @Dan I couldn't think of a good name so I called it bool, and you have to apply the @ since bool is a reserved keyword in C#.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you've written too much code :-)

The following is sufficient:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator bool(Foo foo)
    {
        return !object.ReferenceEquals(foo, null) && foo.Result;
    }
}
```

The compiler will then know how to implicitly convert variables of type `Foo` into `bool`. (And `null` will be converted to `false`).

So, when you write:

```
new Foo() == false
```

The compiler will use the implicit type converter to get a `bool` value from `Foo` and then use the standard equality operator for `bool`.

If we look at the IL that the compiler generates for that expression we find:

```
newobj instance void FooBool.Foo::.ctor()               // new Foo()
call bool FooBool.Foo::op_Implicit(class FooBool.Foo)   // implicit operator (Foo => bool)
ldc.i4.0                                                // false
ceq                                                     // equality operator (bool)
```

Here's a test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AssertTrue(new Foo() == false);
    AssertTrue(false == new Foo());
    AssertFalse(new Foo() != false);
    AssertFalse(false != new Foo());
    AssertTrue(new Foo { Result = true } == true);
    AssertTrue(true == new Foo { Result = true });
    AssertFalse(new Foo { Result = true } != true);
    AssertFalse(true != new Foo { Result = true });
}

static void AssertTrue(bool value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value ? "ok" : "not ok");
}

static void AssertFalse(bool value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value ? "not ok" : "ok");
}
```

It prints `ok` for each test. So this simplified code should fulfill your needs if I understood them correctly.

**UPDATE**

To allow the equality operator to work for instances of `Foo` (which may be null):

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
    {
        return !b.Result;
    }
    else if (object.ReferenceEquals(b, null))
    {
        return !a.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        return a.Result == b.Result;
    }
}
```

You should then also implement the inequality operator:

```
public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

And also override `GetHashCode` + `Equals`

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Result ? 1 : 0;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
    {
        return !this.Result;
    }

    Type t = obj.GetType();

    if (t == typeof(Foo))
    {
        return this.Result == ((Foo)obj).Result;
    }
    else if (t == typeof(bool))
    {
        return this.Result == (bool)obj;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, that this code wouldnt work 100% when comparing 2 Foos or?
Or would the IL implicit convert both side? `new Foo() { Result = false) == new Foo() { Result = false }` this would return false in your code wouldnt it, so I believe that samy's answer is more complete or?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand that you wanted the equality operator to work for Foo instances. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MårtenWikström I don't understand why your == operator for Foo and Foo returns the inverse of the other Foo result when one is null; if FooA = null and FooB = Foo(true) then comparing both will return false, but if FooA = null and FooB = Foo(false) it will return true, which is incorrect? What is the reasoning for this behavior?

Comment: If A is null it should be equal to B if B is either null or has a false result. It is indeed correct to return true when FooA=null and FooB=Foo(false) because you have defined that a null Foo instance shall be implicitly converted into a false boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you explicitly covered all the bases in your code; if needed you must consider the ordering of parameters for the operator so if you want your `Equals` function to be called for both ordering of parameters what you did is right.

However it looks a bit overkill in the case of comparing `Foo` to `bool` since you could simply rely on the implicit conversion. This would allow you to remove all operators between the two types as well as the `Equals` and `NotEquals` methods.

What's more, it would avoid some inconsistency in your code regarding the conversion of a null Foo to boolean. When you pass a null Foo to the `Equals` method it will return `true` whereas in the implicit conversion a null Foo will return `false`:

```
true == (Foo)null; //true
true == Convert.ToBoolean((Foo)null); //false
```

---

In closing, here is how i'd write the Foo class, i think it is sufficient:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        return Equals(foo, fooB);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        return NotEquals(foo, fooB);
    }
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo == null ? false : foo.Result;
    }

    private static bool Equals(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        if (object.Equals(foo, null))
        {
            return object.Equals(fooB, null);
        }

        if (object.Equals(fooB, null))
            return false;

        return foo.Result == fooB.Result;
    }
    private static bool NotEquals(Foo foo, Foo fooB)
    {
        return !Equals(foo, fooB);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not using a try-catch block in your static implicit operator bool block. Just check if Foo is null, if it is return false, otherwise return foo.Result